# Plotting datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, timestamp, seaborn

I am running into an error with a grouped by date dataframe:
`byDate = df.groupby('Date').count()`

```
Date       Value      
2019-08-15 2
2019-08-19 1    
2019-08-23 7    
2019-08-28 4
2019-09-04 7
2019-09-09 2
```

I know that `type(df["Date"].iloc[0])`
returns `datetime.date`

I want to plot the data in such a way, that days, for which no value is available are shown as 0. 
I have played around with 
`ax = sns.lineplot(x=byDate.index.fillna(0), y="Value", data=byDate)`
I am however only able to get this output, where the y-axis indicates that a line is not drawn to 0 for days for which no value is available.

[image]

Comment: Using barchart might be more suitable in this case `ax = sns.barplot(byDate, x=byDate.index.fillna(0), y="Value", data=byDate)`

Comment: Yes, the barplot was also my first choice, since it does not require to set the fillna attribute. However, I would like to use the line plot to show, where the null values actually are and how frequent they are compared to non-null values.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43777934/12422518

Comment: Hmm, at least it got me thinking about creating a df with the value counts, instead of a grouped one. The ffill method will just take the last value and then performs a forward fill as far as I have understood, so instead of a 0, I get the last filled in value. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried creating a new dataFrame object indexed by all the dates ranging from ***startDate*** to ***endDate*** and then filling in the missing values with `0.0`?

The output would looks something like:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2019-08-15','2019-08-19','2019-08-23','2019-08-28','2019-09-04','2019-09-09']).date
byDate = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[2,1,7,4,7,2]},index=dates)

startDate = byDate.index.min()
endDate = byDate.index.max()
newDates = pd.date_range(startDate,endDate, periods=(endDate - startDate).days).date.tolist()
newDatesDf = pd.DataFrame( index=newDates)
newByDate = pd.concat([newDatesDf,byDate],1).fillna(0)

sns.lineplot(x=newByDate.index, y="Value", data=newByDate)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWcKF.png)

Comment: I have done it slightly differently. I have created a series with `size`, instead of `count` and plotted this one. This worked fine.

Comment: @RlikeRun Great! Could you please share with us your solution?

Comment: Sure. So first I have created a new `df`based on the existing dates and the counts for these dates. Based on the dates and the counts I have created a dictionary with the dates as the key and the counts as values. And lastly I have created a date range and set it as the index. This is my code `index.idx = pd.date_range('08-15-2019', '04-20-2020') #creating a range of dates
s = pd.Series(area_dict) #creating a series with the dictionary created above
s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index) #create an index
s = s.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)` And then just simply the normal series plot method.