# pandas fill missing dates every 30 minutes in time series

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, missing-data

I have this situation in my dataset:

```
timestamp                  value

2020-05-02 22:35:05        13.68

2020-05-02 22:05:05        13.86

2020-05-02 21:05:05        14.44

2020-05-02 20:35:05        14.26

2020-05-02 20:05:05        13.85
```

the dataset comes from the detection of the temperature from a sensor, the timestamp should be every 30 minutes and sometimes this does not happen. I should solve this situation by inserting the missing timestamps inside my dataset, I should then associate it with a value that is close to t-1 and t + 1.
Could anyone help me to resolve this situation?

thanks!

Comment: value `13,68`  is not numeric. How do you determine` close`?

Comment: Thx, I corrected it

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/43777881/9249533

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python:Fill in missing datetime values in dataframe and fill forward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777881/pythonfill-in-missing-datetime-values-in-dataframe-and-fill-forward)

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has a [resample function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample) where you can down/up sample timeseries data. From this you can then also apply a function to say how you want to 'fill in' the missing values if there are any.

See the example below for your data. First we make sure that the `timestamp` column is of datetime type, and that the `value` column is numeric (removing the commas first). Then we set the dataframe's index to the timestamp column. Now we resample the data at 30 minute intervals ('30T'). Then we can interpolate the results to fill in the gaps. There are many ways to do this, [see the docs for more info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.interpolate.html?highlight=interpolate#pandas.core.resample.Resampler.interpolate).

```py
import pandas as pd

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'].str.replace(',',''))

result = df.set_index('timestamp') \
  .resample(rule='30T', offset=pd.Timedelta(minutes=5, seconds=5)) \
  .interpolate(method='time')
```

Result is:

```
                      value
timestamp                  
2020-05-02 20:05:05  1385.0
2020-05-02 20:35:05  1426.0
2020-05-02 21:05:05  1444.0
2020-05-02 21:35:05  1415.0
2020-05-02 22:05:05  1386.0
2020-05-02 22:35:05  1368.0
```